# Probability of an integrable R.V.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume $Y \in L_1$ and  $Y^2 \in L_1$ where $L_1$ denotes the set of integrable random variables. Show that $Var(Y)=0$ implies $\mathbb{P}[Y=\mathbb{E}(Y)] =1$ so $Y$ is the equivalent to a constant with probability 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $\mathrm{Var}(Y)=\mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}Y)^{2}]=\int\underbrace{\left(Y(\omega)-\mathbb{E}Y\right)^{2}}_{\geq0}d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$.